# How to observe changes to contents of an object's array property exposed through setter-getter or Proxy

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, getter-setter, iife

#### Using getter/setter

I'm creating an IIFE like below. It returns getters and setters to an array variable stored internally. I wish to intercept changes made to that array - the `console.log` is intended to indicate that in the setter below.

```
const a = (function() {
  let arr = [];

  return {
      get arr() {return arr},
      set arr(v) {
          console.log("new arr", v);
          arr = v;
      },
  }
})();
```

This works fine if I completely reassign `arr`, e.g. `a.arr = [1, 2]`.

But it doesn't intercept changes made to contents of the array, e.g. `a.arr.push(3)` or `a.arr.shift()`.

Looking for any ideas on how to intercept these content changes.

#### Using Proxy

This is an alternate attempt using the new Proxy object:

```
a = (function() {

    let details = {
        arr: []
    }

    function onChangeProxy(object, onChange) {
        const handler = {
            apply: function (target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
                onChange(thisArg, argumentsList);
                return thisArg[target].apply(this, argumentsList);
            },
            defineProperty: function (target, property, descriptor) {
                Reflect.defineProperty(target, property, descriptor);
                onChange(property, descriptor);
                return true;
            },
            deleteProperty: function(target, property) {
                Reflect.deleteProperty(target, property);
                onChange(property, descriptor);
                return;
            }
        };

        return new Proxy(object, handler);
    };

    return onChangeProxy(details, (p, d) => console.log(p, d));

})();
```

The problem remains the same. Still unable to observe changes made to the contents of `a.arr` using anything from `a.arr[0] = 1` to `a.push(3)`.

Comment: Your proxy still only observes the `details` object, not the `arr` value.

Comment: Posted my current solution. Leaving the question open in case someone can provide a cleaner answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update: The elegant solution (courtesy Kris Pruden and Sindre Sorhus)

The solution is based on [this commit](https://github.com/kpruden/on-change/blob/e3a909200f302adb3ede32e3ded045758cb3dde3/index.js) by Kris on Sindre's ['on-change' library](https://github.com/sindresorhus/on-change).

[Explanation of the solution](https://github.com/sindresorhus/on-change/pull/16#issuecomment-449760505), by Kris:

> In the `set` trap, my goal is to determine if the value provided is a `Proxy` produced by a previous call to the `get` trap. If it is such a `Proxy`, any property access will be intercepted by our own `get` trap. So, when I access `value[proxyTarget]` our `get` trap will be invoked, which is coded to return `target` when `property === proxyTarget` (line 46). If the value passed to `set` is not an on-change-created Proxy, then `value[proxyTarget]` is `undefined`.

Full code of the solution:

```
(object, onChange) => {
    let inApply = false;
    let changed = false;

    function handleChange() {
        if (!inApply) {
            onChange();
        } else if (!changed) {
            changed = true;
        }
    }

    const handler = {
        get(target, property, receiver) {
            const descriptor = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, property);
            const value = Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);

            // Preserve invariants
            if (descriptor && !descriptor.configurable) {
                if (descriptor.set && !descriptor.get) {
                    return undefined;
                }
                if (descriptor.writable === false) {
                    return value;
                }
            }

            try {
                return new Proxy(value, handler);
            } catch (_) {
                return value;
            }
        },
        set(target, property, value) {
            const result = Reflect.set(target, property, value);

            handleChange();

            return result;
        },
        defineProperty(target, property, descriptor) {
            const result = Reflect.defineProperty(target, property, descriptor);

            handleChange();

            return result;
        },
        deleteProperty(target, property) {
            const result = Reflect.deleteProperty(target, property);

            handleChange();

            return result;
        },
        apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
            if (!inApply) {
                inApply = true;
                const result = Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList);
                if (changed) {
                    onChange();
                }
                inApply = false;
                changed = false;
                return result;
            }

            return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList);
        }
    };

    return new Proxy(object, handler);
};
```

This has solved my problem, without resorting to the hack of checking for array modifying methods.

---

#### Original solution:

I've sorted this, for now, with help from [David Walsh's post here](https://davidwalsh.name/watch-object-changes). It's still ugly, but works for now.

Updated the `onChanged` Proxy maker with a recursive-ish `get` trap.

```
get: function (target, property, receiver) {
    let retval;

    try {
        retval = new Proxy(target[property], handler);
    } catch (err) {
        retval = Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
    }

    if (mutators.includes(property))
        onChange(target, property, receiver);

    return retval;
},
```

Also added a list of functions to check the get trap against (the ugly, hacky bit):

```
const mutators = [
    "push",
    "pop",
    "shift",
    "unshift",
    "splice",
    "reverse",
    "fill",
    "sort"
]
```

This seems to be working in my testing so far.

Thanks for pointing in the correct direction.